# SQL query for today's date minus two months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all the records in a table where their date of entry is older then 2 months.

Any idea how I can do that?

I haven't tried anything yet but I am on this point:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FB WHERE Dte > GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 370, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDate < DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

Based on your update it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM FB WHERE Dte <  DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM FB
WHERE
    Dte BETWEEN CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-20 00:00:00'
        AND CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-20 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Why would you write this this way? It's grotesquely long compared to the answer from 3 years prior, and probably 4-5 times as slow due to the 4-5 additional system calls to generate the same amount of information.