# GetDate() Function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My mind has gone totally blank this morning. I'm creating a proc and  need it to pull results with a date-related WHERE clause. The WHERE clause should state that the report should look back two months from `GetDate()`.

This is using T-SQL in SQL Server 2012. The column containing the date for the clause is called `[Delivery Date]`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[Delivery Date]` has both date and time and want to consider time as well? then try

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE [Delivery Date] >= DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

If `[Delivery Date]` is only a date or ignore the time part? then try

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE [Delivery Date] >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE [Delivery Date] < DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

MSDN Link for [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
Similar Question: [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425627/sql-query-for-todays-date-minus-two-months)

Answer (score 1):

2 month ago starting the 1st of the month at 00:00

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0)
```

2 month ago starting the same day of month (if applicable) at the same hour

```
DATEADD(mm, -2, GETDATE())
```