# How to retrieve records that are from two months from the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

So what I am trying to do is when I run the query, I want to return all records that were in the month two months from the current month. For example, lets say the current month is November, when the query runs, I want returned all records from September and only September. If I run the query in lets say October, I want all records from August and only August. I am trying to do this in MS SQL. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What's wrong with a `WHERE` that makes use of the `>`/`>=`  and `<`/`<=` operators?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this will help you to get useful answers to your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425627/sql-query-for-todays-date-minus-two-months

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
where datecol >= dateadd(month, -3, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)) and
      datecol < dateadd(month, -2, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```

This is index- and optimizer- friendly.  If you don't care about performance, you can use `datediff()`:

```
where datediff(month, datecol, getdate()) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a nice 1 liner.

WHERE NOW() BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2;

Answer (score 0):

The function `GETDATE()` can be used to retrieve the current month.

The function `DATEADD(datepart,number,date)` can be used to perform operations on dates. For more info look at the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Thus, to retrieve the records from two months before (`-2`) the current month you can use the following:

```sql
DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

In conclusion an example query to select all records that were in the month two months from the current month:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
   WHERE MONTH(month_column) = DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

sources:

- [WHERE Clause to find all records in a specific month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851236/where-clause-to-find-all-records-in-a-specific-month)
- [SQL query for today's date minus two months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425627/sql-query-for-todays-date-minus-two-months)

Comment: Pls add little explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the month part in a variable and then it can be used in the Where clause to filter the month part of the date value is equal to the varoable value.

**Query**

```
Declare @month as int;
Set @month=datepart(month, getdate()) - 2;

Select * from yourTableName
Where month(dateCol) = @month;
```