# How to select records of same day as today from all months and years

Tags: sql-server, date, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have sample data as below:

| Date | Index |
| --- | --- |
| 26-07-2022 | 26 |
| 26-06-2022 | 23 |
| 24-07-2022 | 12 |
| 19-06-2022 | 16 |
| 26-04-2022 | 01 |
| 26-05-2022 | 10 |
| 26-07-2022 | 12 |

I want to select data of latest day from each month. For example if today's date is 26-07-2022 then I want to select all records where date is 26th.

So my output should look like below:

| Date | Index |
| --- | --- |
| 26-07-2022 | 26 |
| 26-06-2022 | 23 |
| 26-04-2022 | 01 |
| 26-05-2022 | 10 |
| 26-07-2022 | 12 |

Do anybody know how can I achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the `DAY` function?

Comment: Let's make this more clear. You want to select rows with the same day as "today" for all prior months within the same year? So everything >= Jan 1 2022,  <= getdate() and where DAY() returns 26.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7926183/smor I want to select records of same day as today for all prior months for all years.

Comment: One way is to write a function which will construct the date for each of the priori months based on todays date. This has issues for example if the date is 30 , Feb month will have an invalid date. Another way is to use the built in function refer following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425627/sql-query-for-todays-date-minus-two-months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data type of the column `[Date]` is `DATE`, use the function [`DAY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE DAY([Date]) = DAY(GETDATE())
  AND [Date] <= GETDATE(); -- you may remove this if it is not needed
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db8c34cf9dcd888c2ac5dbb18121f1bf).