# How to subtract one month from a date using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a date in format `dd/mm/yyyy`. I want to subtract one month from it.

I am using this code but the output is "09/10/2020" I don't know why my code does the subtraction of the year -2 also.

This is my request

```sql
SELECT
    FORMAT(CONVERT (DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CONVERT(char(9), GETDATE()))), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: *"I have a date in format dd/mm/yyyy"* this suggests that your data is being stored in a string based data type (`(n)(var)char`); this is a fatal design flaw, and you should be fixing your design to be using a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes).

Comment: no need to change my column i need solution of my problem

Comment: No, there is certainly a **need** to change your column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query for today's date minus two months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425627/sql-query-for-todays-date-minus-two-months)

Comment: At the very least you need to confirm what data type you are storing this in. Can you confirm it is `varchar`

Answer (score 2):

you need to change it to:

```
select format(CONVERT (date,DATEADD(MONTH, -1,GETDATE())), 'dd/MM/yyyy' )
```

but as Larnu stated. it seems like you need to change the column.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code doesn't work as expected because:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(9), GETDATE());
```

Returns this (at least in my language):

```
Nov  9 20
```

Which is, unfortunately, and again in my language, a valid date (but in {20}20, not {20}22).

Even in the right style (103), `char(9)` would yield `10/11/202` tomorrow, since 9 digits is only enough if only the day or the month (but not both!) can be represented by a single digit.

Don't know why you are converting `GETDATE()` to a string. Just perform date math on it and *then* format it if you need to (using a specific style number, e.g. 103 for d/m/y):

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), 103);
```

I really wouldn't use `FORMAT()` for such simple output, as the CLR overhead really isn't worth it. Ideally you leave it as a date/time type until presentation time - surely your presentation layer can present your date as d/m/y if that's really a wise idea.

And if you are storing or passing dates as strings (and worse, in regional formats like d/m/y) you really should consider fixing that.

Answer (score -4):

First of all,

You could manipulate your Date as a string. If you don't want to change the column, you can always convert from Date to Varchar and then (re)convert it.

Example:
First, convert Date to varchar using the style code '112' ISO for formatting as yyyyMMdd:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = GETDATE();

DECLARE @dateConverted as VARCHAR (8) = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 112));
```

Then you just subtract the month using DATEADD():

```
DECLARE @previousMonth AS VARCHAR (8) = (SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(month, -1, @dateConverted), 'yyyyMMdd'));
```

Finally, convert varchar do Date again:

```
DECLARE @previousMonthConverted AS DATE = (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(date, @previousMonth), 120));
```

Comment: No, we really shouldn't promote bad ideas like storing dates as strings.

Comment: I didn't promote the idea of storing date as a string. Read again. Just gave an idea for manipulation, but still storing as a date. Cheers.

Comment: `You should be storing your Date as a string` <-- this is what I disagree with. If it's not what you meant, you should fix the wording.

Comment: That's true, but don't just comment based on the text. If the code doesn't show that, it's probably a typo, right? Don't start shooting just to drop some comments on stackoverflow and be more constructive and less destructive. Cheers.

Comment: So "Read again" when what I said is _actually written in your answer_ is constructive I guess? Like I said, if you meant something different than what you said, then you should change what you said. _That_ is constructive. I've provided 80 answers here. You've provided two. Don't tell me I'm just dropping comments and not being constructive.

Comment: This is not gonna take us anywhere. Just give your answer and help the guy.

Comment: I did do that. I was trying to help you improve your answer, which was posted over a month after mine. Next time I'll just down-vote and move on.